# Error while archiving react-native iOS project for testflight, app-icon

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to Archive a react-native iOS app in preparation of distributing via TestFlight. I already added app icons of several resolutions, but I am still getting errors of missing app icons.[image: App Icon]

and here is the error.

[image: Error while Archiving]

I also have App Icons Source set to AppIcon in the General tab of the project.

This is a react native app, which I am trying to distribute it to testers via TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

Check your target for the source of App Icons.

[image: App Icons source]

It means only icons inside `AppIcon` are effected.

You could use tool like [MakeAppIcon](https://makeappicon.com) that generate all icons that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I started the react native development from a seed git repo. Even though I had all the icons in Images.xcassets, the problem was, in the "Build Phases" I had another shared resources of another xcassets which was blank (had no icons) in the "Copy Bundle resources". I copied the images from Images.xcassets to that shared resources and I was able to archive it successfully.[image]